# How can I install Ruby to be used as a notebook in the Jupyter Web UI (Mac OS 10.10.5)?

Tags: ruby, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've found several pages that purport to tell me how to do this but I've had no success so far.

FYI, I've never used Ruby or any part of its ecosystem (Gem? That's clever!) so I'm swimming in a sea of new terminology and assumptions.

I have Jupyter 4.1.0 installed. When I boot it with `jupyter notebook` I get the web UI and under the "New" menu and under "Notebooks" I only see Python 2. I would really like to see "Ruby" like I do on the [Try Jupyter](https://try.jupyter.org/) page.

I tried following the instructions on this page:
https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby/tree/master
It seemed to suggest that for an installation involving Python 2 I should use the installation instructions found on the [IPython2 branch](https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby/tree/ipython2). I t actually seemed to suggest that I should do that if I had IPython2. It seems I actually have IPython 4.1.2 but the first instruction set didn't work so. Furthermore, I don't actually understand how IPython factors into all of this as I started using Jupyter when it was already called Jupyter.

When I tried to follow the master branch instructions Gem told me

> iruby requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0

Apparently I have ruby version 2.0.0p481.

Then I wasn't sure how to upgrade ruby. Gem? Brew? Pip? Binary?

I was, eventually, able to install iruby version 1.9 with Gem but it didn't show up in the Jupyter UI. I restarted the Jupyter server, closed the terminal and started it again, etc with no success.

I'm going around in circles here and I'm sure it's slightly less complicated than it seems.

- Is there a config file somewhere that tells Jupyter which kernels to
  load?
- Is there a PATH variable that needs to contain the iruby binary?

Also, unless this statement alludes to a serious misunderstanding somewhere, I'm not (yet) interested in Ruby on Rails. I'm under the impression that is some sort of framework that I may have use for some day. For now, I just want a little playground for ruby. (I know there are online ruby IDEs out there but I really like Jupyter and it seems like I can do it there. So I wanna!!)

Here is a summary of a few of my details so far.

- Mac OS 10.10.5
- Python 2.7.11
- Gem 2.0.14
- IPython 4.1.2
- Jupyter 4.1.0

I have plenty of experience with Python.
I have zero experience with Ruby.

Thank you, in advance, for your help!

Comment: Try rvm to manage multiple ruby versions and retake the steps for iruby install.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade RUBY version. By default OS X comes with ruby 2.0 which is really old as per current standards

For Mac the best way is

`brew install ruby`

which will install the latest version of ruby

Once that is done just install iruby gem

`sudo gem install iruby`

Comment: To register Ruby kernel with Jupyter Notebook, run `iruby register --force`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!

Note: This installs a global ruby and iruby gem. If you run multiple rubys or you want a separate ruby kernel environment for you notebook(s), say using RVM/rbenv/asdf, then don't forget to install the iruby gem for the ruby you're going to register and use.